# How to import some data from one table to another(MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

I am working on a projects. There are two tables, users and mileage_registrants. A module of our website needs users to do another registration except the one for main access to our website. Now the problem is that our clients don't want to do such kind of registration and I don't want to change the whole architecture of the module. So what I want to do is to import user_id from table users to mileage_registrants and set other fields as default or NULL.

The structure of table mileage_registrants is like:

```
'id`, `user_id`, `team_id`,  `team_leader`, `building_name`, `department`, `phone_ext`, `party_registered`, `creation_date`.
```

There are more than 1000 users needed to be done. It is horrible to insert the data one by one. Is there any solution that can quickly get this done? thanks

Answer (score 12):

Getting data from one table to another can be done like this quite easy.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1,column2) SELECT oldcolumn1,oldcolumn2 FROM table2
```

(optionally with a where clause)

Take a look at the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: beat me to the punch. This is correct. Assuming your ID in mileage_registrants is autoincremented, leave this field off the query. If you only need to really import one field, do that field and leave the remaining 10 you mention off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into mileage_registrants (`user_id`, `team_id`,  `team_leader`, `building_name`, `department`, `phone_ext`, `party_registered`, `creation_date` ) 
SELECT user_id,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL from users
```

Comment: no need to set NULL values, insert into one field and select one field from 'users'

Comment: Its needed if the default for some fields is not NULL. Without seeing the DDL  I went the safer route.

Comment: good point. He could always go back and set those fields to default NULL though but in either case i suppose the same really.